# Double arrow between sets meaning?

Tags: notation

From C.E. Patrascu and M. Patrascu's "Computing Order Statistics in the Farey Sequence"
there is a line:

**{all fractions in [0, x) with denominator q} ←→ {reduced fractions with denominator d, for all d|q}**

Note q is an integer, x is real.

What is the meaning of a double arrow between sets? I'm familiar with it as implication, but not in this context. It can't be equality, as the denominators are different. Does it mean the cardinalities are equal? If so, an explanation of that would also be appreciated, as it is not mentioned in the text.

Comment: This probably means that they associate a reduced fraction with its equivalence class

Comment: A double arrow symbol $\longleftrightarrow$ between two sets usually indicates a bijection, therefore I would guess that the author means that there is a bijection between the set of *rational numbers* in $[0,x)$ *that can be written as a fraction of integers with denominator* $q$ and the set of the *pairs* $(n,d)$ such that $d$ divides $q$, $\operatorname{gcd}(n,d)=1$ and $0\le n< dx$. The inverse of that bijection being the map $(n,d)\mapsto \frac nd$.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bijection.  Going to the right, $\frac{n}{q}$ maps to its reduced form; going to the left, $\frac{m}{d}$ maps to $\frac{m(q/d)}{d(q/d)} = \frac{n}{q}$ where $n=m(q/d)$.